# Can dse cassandra audit log enabled for a particular table?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have enabled dse cassandra audit log by following this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/sec/secAuditingCassandraTable.html).

But, the documentation explains about configuring audit log on a keyspace. I need to enable it on a single table inside a keyspace.

For ex: keyspace name : test, has table table1, table2. Audit should be enabled only on table1 not table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the DSE Audit Log is only configurable at the keyspace level, not the table level.

This is done by using the `included_keyspaces` or `excluded_keyspaces` in your DSE yaml. This is the relevant link in the docs http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secAuditEnable.html?hl=included_keyspaces

The link you shared describes how to write audit out to a DSE table (rather than to a file), not how to audit a specific table.

Comment: Thank you @phact. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can enable the audit log on the entire keyspace and filter the log after the fact.